# Updating Master / Details in MVC

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, model-view-controller, edmx

I am trying to update a Master / Details relationship. At the moment my code only updates the master table but does not add anything to the details page.
I can add records to both tables fine but I want to be able to update the master and add new entries to the details at the same time.
Screenshots show the data being passed to my Controller.

[image]

[image]

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult saveEdit(OMR_OrderMaster order)
    {
        bool status = false;

        {
            using (PPPEntities dc = new PPPEntities())
            {
                {

                    db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    status = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
    }
```

At Present no errors are returned but just the Master tabel is being updated

```
namespace PPP2.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class OMR_OrderMaster
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public OMR_OrderMaster()
    {
        this.OMR_OrderDetails = new HashSet<OMR_OrderDetails>();
    }

    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<OMR_OrderDetails> OMR_OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
namespace PPP2.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class OMR_OrderDetails
{
    public int OrderDetialsID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int StockID { get; set; }

    public virtual OMR_OrderMaster OMR_OrderMaster { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us `OMR_OrderMaster` and `OMR_OrderDetails` class definition please.

Comment: Updated Code above

Comment: Are you sure Primary Keys are defined in your sql database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are in EDMX context you have to use `Attach` function like :

```
using (PPPEntities dc = new PPPEntities())
{
     foreach(var details in order.OMR_OrderDetails)
          dc.ORM_OrderDetails.Attach(details);
     dc.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
     dc.SaveChanges();
     status = true;
 }
```

> Be careful in your code you are declaring a `PPPEntities` context but you don't use it. Your code is calling an undefined `db` var.

Answer (score 0):

Using Attach threw an error but changing to add worked in my case
So, thank you for putting me on the right track

```
                foreach (var details in order.OMR_OrderDetails)
                dc.OMR_OrderDetails.Add(details);
                dc.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
                dc.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
```